# How does a SurfaceView handle off screen elements?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I was asking myself how a `SurfaceView` handles drawing outside the visible area. I made some online research but couldn't find anyone that ask or anything that answers the question. So I made some testing, my test setup looks like this:

I draw 5000 circles on a `SurfaceView` with an x-axis offset of -100 and an additional -100 offset for every 1000 circles. The offset is stored in a `Matrix` as a translation and applied to the canvas before drawing using `Canvas.concat()`. The result is a `SurfaceView` with 5000 circles drawn on it but initially they are all outside the visible area and you don't see them on the screen. I ran my test application, applied a translation to the `Canvas`, so that the circle stacks appeared one after another, and measured the frames per second. All update and drawing is done using a simple thread that loops as often as possible.

The measured results are:

- 0 visible circles -> ~ 40 FPS
- 1000 visible circles -> ~ 30 FPS
- 2000 visible circles -> ~ 20 FPS
- 3000 visible circles -> ~ 15 FPS
- 4000 visible circles -> ~ 12 FPS
- 5000 visible circles -> ~ 10 FPS

I need to mention that this is all done using my own 2D engine. Without any elements on it, it runs at 60 FPS. I think the first "missing" 20 FPS could result by my rendering pipeline that iterates over the 5000 elements.

Does anyone know more about the `SurfaceView` or `Canvas` and can explain this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Test setup: Nexus 10, Android 4.2.1, min SDK: 14, target SDK: 17

Comment: Similar question, though I am not sure if this really answer anything it might at least spend some light to it: [Android. . . drawing outside the bounds of a canvas](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24924.0)

Comment: Thank you, that's one reason why I thought about it, sort of. I think I need to measure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the explanation about graphics hardware WarrenFaith posted I measured the difference between drawing all circles and check before drawing. It turns out there is absolutely no difference! To be sure I even increased the circle count to 50000 and both tests ran on about 4 to 5 FPS with no visible circles.